# How to get rgdal/proj 4 to work for mac

Tags: r, rgdal, proj, adehabitathr

I'm having problems trying to use the adehabitatHR package in R. When I load the rgdal package I get the following error message.

```
 > library(rgdal)
Loading required package: sp
rgdal: version: 1.0-7, (SVN revision 559)
 Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
 Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 1.11.1, released 2014/09/24
 Path to GDAL shared files: /usr/local/share/gdal
 Loaded PROJ.4 runtime: Rel. 4.9.1, 04 March 2015, [PJ_VERSION: 491]
 Path to PROJ.4 shared files: (autodetected)
WARNING: no proj_defs.dat in PROJ.4 shared files
 Linking to sp version: 1.2-1
```

I haven't found an answer that's suitable for someone who isn't highly skilled in computer programming (such as [how to upgrade proj4 for rgdal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33381421/how-to-upgrade-proj4-for-rgdal)). The extant answers on this topic are not written in a form that's understandable to a layperson - for example I don't know how to "compile", "clone" etc from the GitHub codes linked in other threads. These answers presuppose (what seems to me to be) a significant amount of programming knowledge that isn't applicable to my field of study. I would appreciate if someone could explain it in a straightforward manner to someone who has basic computer knowledge.

Comment: Do you presently use `homebrew` perchance?

Comment: If so then not knowingly. I'm not familiar with that term

Comment: It's pretty easy to setup: http://brew.sh/ ; This: http://predictiveecology.org/2015/04/24/installing-R-spatial-packages.html doesn't seem so bad as far as a how-to goes. Digression: _"isn't applicable to my field of study"_ is an obviously limiting point of view. IMO learning the ecosystem around a tool is equally as important as being able to wield it for a particular purpose. I'm sure you have & can survive w/o delving, but it seems like a tiny investment in just how to install libraries cld pay dividends in the long run.

Comment: That's actually just a warning, it may not prevent you from doing what you want, and won't cause the program to stop, like an error would.

Comment: But I've  had that warnings and found problems later... [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34333624/trouble-installing-rgdal/37829420#37829420) they provide some notes on the installation that seemed to work to some people, but not to me.